# What is responsible for deleting my pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, scope

I've often wondered,

I know I can create a pointer to an instance of an object at the same time as passing that same pointer as an argument to a function, using the `new` keyword. Like I have below in the `Animation::newFrame` function, given in the example below.

However, I'm also aware that as a general rule I'm responsible for calling `delete` on things that I create using `new`.

So when I call Frame's constructor like so:

```
Frame* myFrame
    = new Frame(new point(0,0), new point(100,100), new point(50,20));
```

Where does the responsibility to eventually free the memory for the 3 points I have created using `new` in the above function call lie?

After all, the above 3 new points don't exactly have names for me to call `delete` on.

I've always sort-of assumed that they belong in the scope of the function they're called in, and they will simply go out of scope with the function. However, lately I've been thinking maybe that is not so.

I hope I've been clear enough here.

Thanks in advance,

Guy

```
struct Frame
    {
    public:
        point f_loc;
        point f_dim;
        point f_anchor;

    //the main constructor:: Creates a frame with some specified values
        Frame(point* loc, point* dim, point* anchor)
        {
            f_loc = loc;
            f_dim = dim;
            f_anchor = anchor;
        }

    };

struct Animation
    {
    public:
        vector<Frame*> frameList;

    //currFrame will always be >0 so we subtract 1
        void Animation::newFrame(int &currFrame)
        {
            vector<Frame*>::iterator it;//create a new iterator
            it = frameList.begin()+((int)currFrame);//that new iterator is 

                    //add in a default frame after the current frame
            frameList.insert(
                        it,
                        new Frame(
                            new point(0,0),
                            new point(100,100),
                            new point(50,20)));

            currFrame++;//we are now working on the new Frame

        }

        //The default constructor for animation. 
        //Will create a new instance with a single empty frame
        Animation(int &currFrame)
        {
                frameList.push_back(new Frame(
                    new point(0,0),
                    new point(0,0),
                    new point(0,0)));

                currFrame = 1;
        }
    };
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this question is purely theoretical. I am aware that there are much better alternatives to raw pointers such as smart pointers. I'm asking simply to deepen my understanding of regular pointers and how to manage them.

Also the example above is taken from a project of mine that is actually C++/cli and c++ mixed (managed and unmanaged classes), so that is why the contructor only accepts `point*` and not passing by value (`point`). Because `point` is an unmanaged structure, and therefore when used within managed code, must be managed by myself, the programmer. :)

Comment: that code can't possibly compile.  type mismatch: f_loc = loc;  also -1.  you should have tried to build it yourself.

Comment: That's exactly why such things should be passed by value (and not created by `new`in the first place). If you create them with `new`you have to call `delete`on them at some point.

Comment: Why do you insist on allocating objects on heap (with `new`)? Why not use temporary objects, like: `Frame myFrame(point(0,0), point(100,100), point(50,20));`. It is cheaper because it avoids expensive heap allocation and memory allocation issues you observed.

Comment: @Andrzej I ask myself this often. I created these structs long ago, and since havent changed them since they've become widely used in my code. They accept `point*` and not `point` for reasons I can no longer remember. Your comment above is completely correct, but I pose this question as a theoretical one, simply for the sake of a deeper understanding of pointers and their owenership.

Comment: @Hulk taking my above comment into account, then do you mean that here that at some point in my Frame constructor, that I am to call `delete loc;`, `delete anchor` and `delete dim`? (If I were to use raw and not smart pointers.)

Comment: @thang: "can't possibly compile" is a bit strong; this is clearly a snippet. That said, Guy, it's good form to mention things like `point*` to `point` conversions :)

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean Yes, you should delete them, if the `point*` to `point` conversion copies the values it needs. (apologies for my odd comments - SO is loading in comments from others long after I've posted mine!)

Comment: Your current code is also not exception safe. If one of the `new` calls or `point` constructors throws an exception you will leak the one(s) that succeeded.

Comment: @BenHymers Thank you. I will be more clear in future.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I haven't really applied any exception handling/graceful degradation to the point class as I can't see where it can really throw exceptions at me. FYI `point` is simply composed of 2 GLfloats.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean the `new` still makes it exception unsafe. If one of the `new`s throw then any of the `point`s which have already been `new`ed will be leaked.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out. What kind of abnormalities could possibly lead `new` to throw? I've never had `new` throw an exception at me before. Or do you just mean the constructor after the `new` call?

Comment: If `new` can't allocate memory for whatever reason it throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: @Blastfurnace cheers, will look into handling this exception.

Comment: The rather questionable use of an overloaded `operator =` aside, is there any reason you can't simply allocate these points on the stack since your `Frame` class makes copies of those anyway? `point a(0,0), b(0,0), c(0,0); Frame f(&a, &b, &c);`

Comment: @T.C. Why not overload an `operator=` into my point class? Everyone keeps looking at this as a negative, but nobody can seem to tell me why.

Comment: @T.C. Also I explain why I can't in the edit section of the question. This project features c++/cli and c++/cli doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clarifying and, often, enforcing the semantics of resource ownership is the responsibility of the programmer.  This can be tricky business, especially when dealing with raw pointers as you are here, in an environment where resource ownership hasn't been given any real design consideration.  The latter is prevalent not only in toy programs written by rookie programmers, but in production systems written by people with decades of experience who should have known better.

In your actual case above, the `Frame` object must itself be responsible for `delete`ing the 3 pointers passed in, and whatever constructed the `Frame` itself must be responsible for `delete`ing that.

Because resource ownership is such a minefield, programmers long ago invented a number of techniques to clarify the semantics of ownership, and make it much more difficult to introduce bugs and leaks by careless programmers.  These days, in C++ it is considered a best-practice to avoid raw pointers and, in fact, dynamic allocation altogether whenever possible -- in major part because resource ownership is such a dangerous minefield.

In C++, the primary idiom used to accomplish these goals is RAII and the main tools used are `auto_ptr` (C++03), `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and their ilk.  Boost also provides a number of so-called "smart pointers".  Many of these parallel those found in C++11 (in fact, the new smart pointers in C++11 were initialliy developed by Boost), but there are also some that go beyond, such as `intrusive_ptr`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am familiar and experienced with smart pointers and the RAII method. 
 Do you mean here that at some point in my `Frame` constructor, that I am to call `delete loc;`, `delete anchor` and `delete dim`? (If I were to use raw and not smart pointers.)

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean If you're `new`ing them on the way in and then `delete`ing them inside, then why are you using `new` at all? Just pass the `point`s by value...

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean John said it clearly enough: **don't use `new` or `delete`**.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code needs to be fixed up to make it compile - you probably can't assign a `point*` to a `point` for example (depending on the implementation of `point`).

Once you've done that, the answer to your question is that `Animation` will need to free everything in its `frameList`, and `Frame` will need to free the passed in `point*`s. Raw pointers will not be deleted for you.

A better answer (though not quite what you asked for) is that you should be using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` to manage memory - these will delete the pointed-to object for you. That's definitely what I'd do for `frameList` - make it a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Frame>>`.

In this case, there's probably no good reason to be using pointers for `point`s (I'm guessing they're just coordinates, and are very cheap to copy) - I'd just pass them by value or const reference. That way there are no heap allocations involved and it's much simpler.

Comment: +1 for passing a point by value or const reference.  It is much simpler and probably will perform a lot better since it won't require a bunch of small heap allocations.

Comment: Thanks, I know that this example wouldn't compile alone. My actual `point` struct actually contains multiple operator= overloads that allow for `point*` to `point` assignment.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean That's horrible!

Comment: @SebastianRedl Why? As the answer correnctly guessed, `point` is simply 2 GLfloats. The operator=() function simply copies those values from one point to another. Or from a point* to a point. It's robust and VERY readable.

Comment: Any type T for which `T t; T u = &t;` is legal and does the same thing as `T u = t;` is a horrible abuse of implicit conversions and/or operator overloading and can only sow confusion in the long term. There is nothing readable **or** robust about weakening the type system so. For example, this allows Java-like `point p = new point(1, 2);` to compile and apparently work, except that it *leaks memory*.

Comment: I now understand I think. So by overloading the = operator for simple copying assignments between pointers and values, I'm inadvertently compromising the much more crucial application of the `=` symbol, which is initialisation of new instances (potentially)?

Comment: Yep. It's more normal to provide a copy constructor and assignment operator (taking `const T&` or just `T`), then if you want to assign from a pointer, do `T* t; T u = *t;`, that is, dereference the pointer to do the assignment (but of course initialise `t` first!).

Answer (score 1):

A garbage collector, a smart pointer, sometimes it is automatic (if you allocate from the stack). Basically, it is you who is responsible, but you can delegate the responsibility elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If the function you are calling does not state explicitly that it will take ownership of passed pointers `delete`ing them when done, it is your responsability to `delete` anything you `new` yourself.

Comment: So as in my example above, can i call `delete` on a functions arguments, so long as they're pointers?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your code snippet, current memory policy is "passing the ownership". E.g. you create 3 instances of point, then pass them into Frame constructor - right from this moment the Frame instance is responsible to manage that 3 points memory. So, it means you have to provide a destructor for Frame class which will be responsible of memory deletion for each of 3 points stored as a member.

All that above is about "raw memory" tecnique, which is not necessary nova days. Use smart pointers instead. For example, std::auto_ptr is a nice candidate here (but be aware about some pitfalls: if you copy one auto_ptr to another, source will be cleared to NULL, destination will own the memory). Another wide-spreaded candidate here is boost::shared_ptr (it even included into latest standarts of C++ as a part of tr1:: namespace). And don't forget: you have to understand memory policy intended for a smart pointer you choose. Otherwise, you will end up talking with ghosts of destroyed instances or your instances will be never freed like a genie in a bottle.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the conventions.  This looks like part of
a GUI, and the *usual* conventions in a GUI is that the
containing object becomes responsible for the `delete` once it
has been passed the pointer.  Thus, `Animation` would `delete`
all of the pointers in `frameList` in its destructor, and
`Frame` would delete any pointers it held in its destructor.
(Note that this convention is very particular to GUIs, however,
and that in most other contexts, other conventions will be
used.)

Having said that, it's also very atypical in C++ for a value
like `Point` to be allocated dynamically to begin with, and
there would be no pointers to them either.

Answer (score -1):

sorry, did not fully read.
The responsibility is yours to delete the objects you just created, if you don't have references to the points you should create a destructor inside your frame object.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr380.htm

```
    class X {
    public:
      // Constructor for class X
      X();
      // Destructor for class X
      ~X();
    };
```

X::~X() is automatically called on the X object delete.

Please do correct me if I am wrong.